# Use template date filters in custom template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I want to use Django template date filters inside a custom template tag. Is that possible?

My end goal is to be able to use it like this:

```
{{parcel.pickup_dates|delivery_dates_formating}}
```

Problem is, that "pickup_dates" can be array of 1 or 2 or 3 elements.
My desired output is:

- "Sunday, 21 September" if one element,
- "Satardau - Sunday, 21-22 September" if 2 elements,
- "Friday - Sunday, 20-22 September" if 3 elements,

Currenly my temlpate tag looks like this:

```
def delivery_dates_formating(value):
  if len(value) == 1:
    return [value[0]]
  if len(value) == 2:
    return [value[0], value[1]]
  if len(value) == 3:
    return [value[0], value[2]]
```

And in template I used to use something like:
`{{parcel.delivery_date|date:'E  j, l'|capfirst}}`

I woul like to use django tempaltes date filtes, as it handels localisation.
Is that possible?